# OOP - is it better to pass big controller objects to children, or have children dispatch events?

Tags: oop, events, structure

I'm a fairly experienced programmer, but I've always struggled with this particular issue..
You have your main class that maybe displays pop-ups over everything else, transitions between screens and so forth, and then you have the screen objects themselves, and the pop-up objects. when you click "close" on a pop-up, or click "go to a new screen" on a screen, or whatever it may be, these objects then need to communicate with the main class and tell it to do stuff. And often you need to pass data to the main class aswell. In your experience does it work out better to have the children dispatch events with data, that the main class picks up, or somehow pass the main class down to all the children through constructors, and have a bunch of public methods in the main class that the children can call?
or are both equally valid?

edit: And also, what made me post this: In my game, the user goes through a bunch of different menu screens, and in each screen, he adds something to a game-config object that at the end will be used to generate the gameScreen. I dont want to keep saying dispatchEvent("addValueToGameConfig", value) or something, i just want to say bigController.gameConfig.value = "whatever";

Answer (score 0):

If the hierarchy of children is deep, I would go for events or observer. It leads to a lower coupling between classes. Any substantial refactoring of your main class can have a huge avalanche effect on the dependent children. They become too knowledgeable (higher change of breaking Law of Demeter) about their parent and take on effectively an additional responsibility (arguably breaking SRP) besides managing their own state, of informing it constantly about their own state in a custom manner compatible with their parent. Firing a specialized meaningful notification about their state change into "space", not just about an arbitrary property change, releases them from worrying about the parent's state. It is a parent's duty now to be informed about changes of the state of its children. Furthermore, having a set of meaningful events can lead to narrower public interface of children. It may as well help readability, not having to constantly go up and down through the hierarchy.